# Drop / ignore current transaction and use upcoming transaction if available

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have 3 methods defined the following way. `methodX` and `methodY` are defined in different classes. `methodY` and `methodZAsync` are defined in same class.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void methodX(){
    .....
    methodY();
    methodZAsync(); //
}


@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void methodY(){
    .....
    someDatabaseOperations();
    .....
}


@Async
public void methodZAsync(){
    .....
    pollingBasedOnDataOperationsOfMethodY();
    .....
}
```

The problem here is, methodZAsync requires `methodY()`'s DB operations to be committed before it can start it's work. And this fails because `methodZAsync` runs in a different thread.

One option is to make `methodY`'s transaction to use `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`. But since `methodY` is used in multiple places with a different use cases, I'm not allowed to do that.

I've checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833306/using-async-inside-a-transaction-in-spring-application) but `TransactionSynchronization` is an interface and Im not sure what to do with rest of the un-implemented methods.

So I thought, instead of making changes in `methodY()`, If I can somehow make `methodX()` to tell `methodY()` to use a new transaction(naive way: close current running transaction), It'll fix the things for me.

Is this doable from `methodX()` without having to modify `methodY()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new wrapper method around methodY() that creates a new transaction. Then you can call this new method from methodX() without impacting any other use cases.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void methodX(){
    .....
    methodYInNewTxn();
    methodZAsync(); //
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void methodYInNewTxn() {
    methodY();
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void methodY(){
    .....
    someDatabaseOperations();
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer spring boot, there is also

> @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)

method are there go through. Hope you will get your proper answer